# Parallel.ForEach add and read ConcurrentBag, is safe?

Tags: .net, vb.net, multithreading, parallel-processing

¿It's safe and correct, inside parallel.foreach, add and read to/from a concurrent bag?

**Example (in VB.net)**:

```
Dim myConcurrentBag As New ConcurrentBag(Of myClass)

Parallel.ForEach(elementList, Sub(element)
   Try
        Dim newObject as New myClass
       
        newObject.Property1 = element.PropertyX
        
        ' Check if item is inserted inside myConcurrentBag
        ' ¿IS THIS LINE CORRECT?
       If (myConcurrentBag.Select(Function(x) x.Property1).Contains(newObject.Property1)) Then
           Return
       End If
       myConcurrentBag.Add(newObject)

   Catch ex As Exception
       ' Log exception
   End Try
End Sub)
```

And finally, **this is the best way to do it, right?**:

```
Dim myConcurrentDictionary As New ConcurrentDictionary(Of String, myClass)

Parallel.ForEach(elementList, Sub(element)
   Try
        Dim newObject as New myClass
       
        newObject.Property1 = element.PropertyX
        
        ' Check if item is inserted inside myConcurrentDictionary 
        ' ¿IS THIS LINE CORRECT?
       If (myConcurrentDictionary.ContainsKey(newObject.Property1)) Then
           Return
       End If
       
       myConcurrentDictionary.TryAdd(newObject.Property1, newObject)

   Catch ex As Exception
       ' Log exception
   End Try
End Sub)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand your intention is to have unique items in terms of PropertyX after the execution of Parallel.ForEach is completed.

As enumeration of ConcurrentBag runs over a point in time snapshot of the content, another task may insert an object with the same value of the property without Select() seeing this new object, and thus the uniqueness requirement will not be met.

Please check this question as well -- [Adding and removing elements of a ConcurrentBag during enumeration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16952400/adding-and-removing-elements-of-a-concurrentbag-during-enumeration)

Comment: Thank you, I was thinking this too, but I was not sure 100 %: `another task may insert an object with the same value of the property without Select() seeing this new object`. So... using instead a ConcurrentDictionary is safe?

Comment: I'd say it not safe as well, because for ConcurrentDictionary the docs say that the enumerator 'may' see inserted objects, but 'may' usually denotes something that is not a mandatory requirement or is not guaranteed. Why do you design this as a parallel operation? Do you really need it to be parallel?

Comment: Now that you mention it, I don't need it at all, I can group the elements first and then go through them in parallel. Was a question that came to me, however, thank you !!!